# Give agents on patch the same value that patches have NETLOGO

Tags: netlogo, agent

I have a model where there are multiple animals in a den

```
patches-own [den-ID]
```

where the dens are pink and the number of dens is controlled with a slider global var

```
ask patches with [pcolor = pink] [set den-ID random n-dens]
```

Now, I want agents that spawn on that patch to set their own parameter "family" to a value equal to the den-ID that they spawn on - therefore having a group of animals that can be traced back to a den site and all share a home range.

I have tried many solutions but cant get anything to work.

basically something like

```
set family (family = den-id of patch-here)
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer: `ask turtles [ set family patch-here ]`

Down below is how we arrived there

---

You seem a bit confused in your Netlogo syntax.
`=` is only used for logical expressions in Netlogo, not for setting variables. For that you use `set`.
If you want to use `of` to access variables of another agent, you need to encase the variable in square brackets: `[den-id] of patch-here`.

The solution you are looking for looks something like the following:

```
ask turtles [ set family [den-id] of patch-here ]
```

It can be made even easier. A turtle can directly access the variables of a patch that they are on without needing to name that patch.

```
ask turtles [ set family den-id ]
```

I noticed another thing in your code. Nothing in `set den-ID random n-dens` prevents multiple dens of having the same number. There are numerous ways of doing it, for example with a `while` loop where you increment the current-ID each time.

```
set current-ID 1
    while [any? patches with [pcolor = pink and den-ID = 0]] [
        ask one-of patches with [pcolor = pink and den-ID = 0] [set den-ID current-ID]
    set current-ID current-ID + 1
    ]
```

You could even opt to forget about den-id and just let the turtles remember their den itself:

```
ask turtles [ set family patch-here ]
```

Comment: Or forget about coordinates, and let the turtles remember the patch they spawned on : set family patch-here. You may want to edit this answer to make that the top-most solution.

Comment: @TurtleZero oh right, why did I even think of coordinates?

Comment: lol, happens to us all. :)